# Why does SQL Server continues to work after deleting the login for the Virtual Account

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

In my SQL Server 2012 instance, I'm using using a domain account to run the main SQL Server service.  When I log into the instance via SSMS, I do not see this domain account as a login, but I do see the following Virtual Account:

> NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER

So far so good.  From everything I've read, my domain account does not need a login to the instance because everything is running under the Virtual Account.

While exploring this with my coworker, I deleted the login for the Virtual Account.  I thought everything would stop working at this point, but instead, everything was fine.  I restarted the services, even restarted the whole VM.  Everything seems to be fine.  I'm able to create new databases, with the associated log and data files being created in folders that only admins and the Virtual Account have permission to.

Could anyone shed some light on what's going on?  Because this means I don't actually understand how Virtual Accounts work.

<< Edit >>

I think maybe the question I should be asking is, does the account the SQL Service is running under (as seen in the 'Logon' tab in SQL Server Configuration Manager) need sysadmin privileges in the SQL instance?  By default, it is granted sysadmin but removing the privileges seems to make no differece.  I can delete the account entirely from the instance and everything seems to be fine.

Comment: If you start a service against an account that doesn't exist you get an error. What happens when you open the services applet and restart the service there? Double check what is set up in the 'Logon' tab against the SQL Service

Comment: Nick.McDermaid: Thanks Nick, the Logon for the SQL Service is using a minimally privileged domain account. I have restarted the service after deleting the Virtual Account from the SQL instance.  Everything appears to be fine.  I think maybe I should update my question as maybe it's not too clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really the question has nothing to do with Virtual Accounts. You are simply asking: Can a SQL Server instance run if the service account is removed from the instance logins?

According to [Configure Windows Service Accounts and Permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx) the service account is provisioned as a syadmin member login during setup:

> - The per-service SID of the SQL Server service is provisioned as a Database Engine login. The per-service SID login is a member of the `sysadmin` fixed server role.

And there is [KB2620201](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2620201) explaining the bad things that can happen if you undo this:

> By removing the service SID logins or by removing them from the sysadmin server role, problems can result for various components of SQL Server that connect to SQL Server Database Engine. Some problems include the following:
>
> - SQL Server Agent cannot start or connect to a SQL Server service
> - SQL Server Setup programs encounter the problem that is mentioned in the following Microsoft Knowledge Base article [KB955813](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/955813)

So, there you have it. It works, but you may run into issues. Is not about the instance itself, but about *other* processes that run as the same account and attempt to connect to the instance.